# Current divider usage

Tags: current, phasor

I was solving this exercise where I have to find the current through each of the circuit branches. Sorry if the image is a bit confusing but after determining the current I I used the current divider formula to find the current in each of the branches. Apparently I got the wrong answer but I can't understand what I have done wrong.

[image: Problem with calculations]

([Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FSoNRiJRvaGzuJAnDlOHRwBU_DhcTdrs/view?usp=drivesdk))

Comment: Your total \$Z\$ and total \$I\$ look good to me.

Comment: I was doing the exercise in this video and both I and Z are correct but i1 and i2 are not https://youtu.be/LWBXD29VNJI

Comment: I don't get your approach, for now. But the answers I get using my approach are: \$i_1=0.225615314 - j0.0651777575 \equiv 0.234841245 \angle -16.1134182^\circ\$ and \$i_2=-0.0948040109 - j0.32816773\equiv 0.341587265 \angle -106.113418^\circ\$.

Comment: Thanks JYelton! Adding the image really helps.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and answer.That is the right result but how did you get that?

Comment: Do you still need help with this? Your use of the total current in your formula isn't applied correctly. For example, for \$i_1\$ the current will be the voltage at the common unknown node in your circuit divided by \$16\:\Omega\$. This implies that there should be a division by that value in the expression. But there isn't.  You want to compute \$i_1=\frac{V_x}{16\:\Omega}=\frac{V_s - I\cdot \left(4\:\Omega+j\,20\:\Omega\right)}{16\:\Omega}=\frac34\:\text{A}-I\cdot\frac{4\:\Omega+j\,20\:\Omega}{16\:\Omega}\$. But that's not what you did. You need more explanation?

Comment: You could also write:\$\begin{align*}p&=1-\frac{4\:\Omega+j \, 20 \:\Omega }{4\:\Omega+j\,20\:\Omega + \left(16\:\Omega\mid\mid\left(-14\,j \:\Omega+25\,j\:\Omega\right)\right)}\\i_1&=p \cdot \frac{V_s}{16 \: \Omega }\\i_2&=p \cdot  \frac{V_s}{-14\,j\:\Omega+25\,j\:\Omega}\end{align*}\$where ***p*** is the divider percentage of \$V_s\$ at the unknown node, \$V_x\$.

Comment: No, I think I got. Just correct me if I'm wrong please but the I i determined isn't necessarily the current i marked with an I on the circuit right? Once again thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm heading out *right now* so I cannot directly address your question at this time. When back, I'll check and see if you've resolved this in your head. If not, or if you would appreciate further help, I'll write up an answer then. It's easy enough.

Comment: Sure, I would definitely appreciate so....

Comment: I've added an answer that I hope helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhAMZE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(By the way, if you plan to use this site again you should learn to use the *included* schematic editor. It automatically numbers the parts for you and that provides us with an easier, more specific way to address ourselves to your schematic and questions. It's not perfect. As you can see above, it insists on adding "F" and "H" where it's not wanted. But we can all live with these warts.)

For more explanation about why I laid this out as I did, see **Note** below.

I completely agree with your approach in finding the total \$Z\$ and the total \$I\$ for the circuit. You have \$R_1\$ in series with \$L_1\$ in series with the parallel impedance of \$R_2\$ and \$C_1+L_2\$. To compute \$I_{_\text{TOTAL}}=\frac{V_{_\text{S}}}{Z_{_\text{TOTAL}}}\$, you need to find \$Z_{_\text{TOTAL}}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
Z_{_\text{TOTAL}}&=Z_1+\left(R_2 \mid\mid Z_2\right)\\&=\left(4\:\Omega+j\,20\:\Omega\right) + \left(16\:\Omega \mid\mid \left[-j\,14\:\Omega+25\,j\:\Omega\right]\right)\\
&=9.13527851 + j\,27.469496\Leftrightarrow 28.9486878 \:\angle\: 71.6048952^\circ\\&\therefore\\I_{_\text{TOTAL}} &=0.130811304 - j\,0.393345488\Leftrightarrow 0.414526561 \:\angle\: -71.6048952^\circ
\end{align*}$$

You found similar results. So that's good.

I think where you went wrong (and this is offered with respect, because I think you were actually pretty smart here -- just that you got it backwards) is that you constructed two ratios, \$\frac{Z_2}{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}\$ and \$\frac{R_2}{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}\$, as a means of dividing up the total current in the circuit.

But what I think you forgot here (the thing you got backwards, so to speak) is that you really wanted the ratio of each branch ***admittance*** to the total ***admittance***. This is why I think your brain is working really well. It's just that you forgot to realize to first convert the impedences to admittances. So you were very close.

Let's see what happens when we apply your concept but instead use the correct objects, namely the admittances:

$$\begin{align*}
i_1&=I_{_\text{TOTAL}}\cdot \frac{\frac1{R_2}}{\frac1{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}}=I_{_\text{TOTAL}}\cdot \frac{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}{R_2}\\\\&=0.225615314 - j\,0.0651777575\Leftrightarrow 0.234841245 \:\angle\: -16.1134182^\circ\\\\
i_2&=I_{_\text{TOTAL}}\cdot \frac{\frac1{Z_2}}{\frac1{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}}=I_{_\text{TOTAL}}\cdot \frac{R_2\mid\mid Z_2}{Z_2}\\\\&=-0.0948040109 - j\,0.32816773\Leftrightarrow 0.341587265 \:\angle\: -106.113418^\circ
\end{align*}$$

And those are the right answers.

Your basic idea was on the right track. You just got mixed up about the objects upon which your idea applies.

We've all made such mistakes and I think you are going to do just fine on this stuff. And this kind of question you wrote is perhaps the classic kind of student question we should see presented here. You had a clear description of the problem you were working on and you showed all of your work. In addition, you showed enough about how you applied your thinking so that we could work out where you went wrong. If every student question were like this, I believe this site would find far more joy and readiness in helping answer them. So +1 for that!

### Note

I've arranged things so that the divider in a way that eliminates having to add the source voltage. It's not necessary to see it or to see the wires busing power between it and the parts; and those wires just get in the way of seeing the remaining important bits. Also, I've arranged things so that we can use a conventional schematic drafting sheet of paper where currents flow from top to bottom (yes, I know this is AC) and where signal flows from left to right. (In this case, the schematic doesn't have a signal to worry about.) If you consistently draft your schematics to follow rules like this, you'll find them to be more *understandable*.

I like to think of it like a *curtain* or *sheet* where currents flowing from top to bottom are like the flow of a river downstream. Signals then propagate across that river from one side to the other side. These signals require that flow in order to operate, so to speak. It's a picturesque way of seeing things and it pretty much always works better than other alternatives. But there are times, such as with some power supply schematics, where the busing around of power is the important thing to show and highlight to make the schematic better understood. So it's not a hard and fast law. The main point is to have the schematic communicate with others and to do that you need to emphasize the parts and sections to which attention must be drawn and to avoid wasting "ink" on stuff that doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort in explaining this to me. I can't imagine the work you went through to make this but it all came really clear while I was reading it. Once again thanks, I am really grateful.

Comment: @TomásLopes I'm glad it helped. It wasn't hard work. And I owe a debt to the generosity of those who also helped me. What work I provided is an honor and your kind words are more reward to me than I deserve. If this is a satisfactory answer, you are allowed to select it as an answer. This has a few effects, but the main one is to provide closure and let others know you don't need a second answer. It will also give you a few points. (It gives me points, too, but frankly I don't care about that. So don't do this for me.) It's the last step of asking a question.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't I could do that, I don't really care about the points too but I hope this way people with the same question get to see this. Thanks once again and have a great day.

Comment: @TomásLopes You, too. I think you'll do well. Best wishes!